# assigning values to radio buttons on Lotus Script

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a file. I would like to read values from the file and set radio button values according to what is read. And then save them to file, thereby persisting the values. Can any of you outline how this is done? I'm sure it might be simple, but I don't seem to get it right :(

Kind Regards,
Carlos Botelho

Comment: Please add some code to show us, where you fail. Stackoverflow is not there to deliver solutions but to help you with your own code.

Comment: Is this for the client or for the web?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the client, you would set the values you want into a multi-value field on the form, and let the radio button read it's values from that field.